# ElasticSearch create/update certain index documents with strong consistency

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create/update certain ES index documents with strong consistency instead of eventual consistency ? If so, please show an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the required [write consistency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-consistency) for each single index request.

If you want data written to every replica before returning to the user, you just have to add

```
"consistency": "all"
```

to your index operation.

Comment: How can I do that via ElasticSearch’s REST interface? For example in a POST request to create a new document with strong consistency?